# Make readline wait for input in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to make my code ask me for a "TRUE" or "FALSE" value before proceeding.

It currently works fine if I run it one line at a time, however when I run all the code at once in RStudio it simply proceeds without waiting for user input and records a value of "" for my parameter.

```
raw <- readline("TRUE or FALSE -- this is a validation run: ")


if (raw == "F" | raw == "FALSE" | raw == "False"){
validation <- F
} else{
  validation <- T
}
rm(raw)
```

Ideally, I would like an answer that works regardless of how I run it -- `RScript`, `source` within RStudio, or running it (i.e. selecting the code and pressing `run` or ctrl-enter).

Comment: you could check all the possibilities of f/F/false/False/FALSE/fasle/etc with `if (toupper(unlist(strsplit(raw, ''))[1]) == 'F')`

Comment: Caution: `readline` is only for use in interactive mode.

Comment: @BondedDust Ah, ok, so I need `readLines` then?

Comment: `readLines` is not set up for a prompt. You need to describe how this will be used. Using Rscript is different than interactive use. You need to answer the first comment question. If you are "in RStudio", then most people would assume its for interactive console use. Just don't assume you can use it with Rscript or running from a system command line.

Comment: @BondedDust  Well, I am in RStudio now like I was saying, though I'd certainly **like** a solution that would be robust to any of those ways of running it. Is that impossible?

Comment: I can source this in rstudio and it prompts me for the validation run before continuing, but it won't work in non-interactive mode, ie, Rscript

Comment: @rawr agreed, if I `source` it it's okay in RStudio but if I `run` it it's not. I can proceed with what I'm doing but I think I'll leave this question open to see if there's an answer that's encompassing of the different ways of running it since that would be highly useful. I edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want to do this in interactive mode then you already have answers but not for use with Rscript. For that instance you need to send messages to the console with `cat`:

If this test file is named 'prompt.r' and is in the directory where you are working in a system console session:

```
cat("a string please: ");
a <- readLines("stdin",n=1);
cat("You entered")
 str(a);
cat( "\n" )
```

Then you can run it from the command line as

```
$ Rscript prompt.r
```

If you want an all-purpose script then this would run your script under interactive conditions and my script for non-interactive ones:

```
if (interactive() ){raw <- 
             readline("TRUE or FALSE -- this is a validation run: ")

                if (raw == "F" | raw == "FALSE" | raw == "False"){
               validation <- F
                 } else{
                     validation <- T
                       }
           rm(raw)  } else{
#  non-interactive
cat("a string please: ");
a <- readLines("stdin",n=1);
cat("You entered")
 str(a);
cat( "\n" )}
```

Comment: Is there a better way to combine interactive mode and script mode?

Comment: An answer to a request for a "better" solution requires some sort of software metric that is currently not being expressed.

Comment: Don't know what's you mean, at least, in python and ruby, you don't need to separate the two way.

Comment: If your software metric is "do it like Python or Ruby" then I don't see a way to satisfy the request. R has a "split personality". Some function work in interactive mode and some functions do not. R depends on OS specific system level functions for its console interactions that are different than input/output in scripting mode. You might want to look at `littler` or `Shiny` as an alternate.

Answer (score 19):

Are you running the code by highlighting the lines and clicking run? If so, that could be your problem because R is line-by-line entering your code in the terminal.

Instead, write your script (or comment out the parts you're not testing) and click the source button. Then R waits for user response instead of inputting the line after readline() into readline().

I had the same problem as you, which prompted me to look for an answer. But then I tried this different method of executing the code and it worked.

Comment: This actually solved my problem, as long as the original code is being sourced, readLines() seems to stop and wait for user input.

Comment: Right, but Hack-R said he wanted an Rscript-able answer and using the "Source" button in some IDE is not that.

Answer (score 9):

The reason why `readline` is "not waiting for input" is, according to the manual (`?readline`):

> In non-interactive use the result is as if the response was RETURN and
> the value is "".

You have stumbled on one of the "surprising" features of R.

`<rant>`
Why `readline()` works in "interactive mode" only is a complete mystery for me, since it's a perfectly acceptable use case to ask for user input from within a script. Python, for instance, gives you the `input(prompt)` function which you may invoke whenever you need it.
`</rant>`

A relatively convenient way of getting around this mess is to define a function ("Every programming problem can be solved by yet another level of indirection"...):

```
user.input <- function(prompt) {
  if (interactive()) {
    return(readline(prompt))
  } else {
    cat(prompt)
    return(readLines("stdin", n=1))
  }
}
```

A positive side-effect is that you can add all sorts of nice input validation in `user.input()`. But I doubt that that was the intention behind the bizarre behaviour of `readline()`.

Answer (score 4):

Although it requires interactive mode, I found the `askYesNo()` function within the *utils* package to provide a nice, simple user interface for TRUE/FALSE (or more accurately Yes/No) questions. For example, the following code would produce the following dialog.

[image: Yes No Dialog]

- Yes returns `TRUE`
- No returns `FALSE`
- Cancel returns `NA`

Answer (score 0):

Using svDialogs may let you do this.

It's not exactly using readline, but does achieve a similar outcome to what you're looking for.

The code won't run until the dialog box has been filled:

```
library(svDialogs)

raw <- dlgInput("TRUE or FALSE -- this is a validation run: ",Sys.info()["raw"])$res


if (raw == "F" | raw == "FALSE" | raw == "False"){
validation <- F
} else{
  validation <- T
}
rm(raw)
```

Comment: Help page for that functions currently: "The 'RStudio' version of this dialog box does not allow for an empty string. So, for better portability, try never to expect an empty string from the user (the 'Cancel' button is there to dismiss the dialog box). On MacOS, single and double quotes are temporarily replaced by their slanted versions (unicode characters u3032 and u2033, respectively) because the command that triggers the dialog box does not allow quotes inside strings. Regular quotes are reset on the output. This is the only hack we found that was working. Better solutions are welcome!"

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a function set an "if" conditional sentence with "is.na()" then execute "readline()" again if the value entered is null.
see below:

```
readinteger <- function()
{ 
  n <- readline(prompt="Enter an integer: ")
  n <- as.integer(n)
  if (is.na(n)){
    n <- readinteger()
  }
  return(n)
}
print(readinteger())
rm(list=ls())
```