# R run not source a file for interactive input

Tags: r, rstudio

R has a subtle distinction between running and sourcing a file. Source assumes that the input is valid R code. I have a function which asks for interactive input via `readline()` which prompts the user for a string. I have recorded the desired input in a file, but cannot figure out how to run things from a file.

Here's an example, a small function that asks for text interactively and prints it out:

```
spacefun <- function() {
  text <- readline("Input text: ")
  print(text)
}
```

A separate file `test.R` calls that function and supplies the text.

```
spacefun()
Test Line
```

`source()` and `parse()` both throw errors on the whitespace:

```
Error in source("~test.R", echo = TRUE) : 
  ~test.R:2:6: unexpected symbol
1: spacefun()
2: Test Line
```

Thoughts?

Comment: `readline` is only for interactive use, why do you need it to work this way?

Comment: I'm working on a package where interactive input is the best way to create a certain object with a complicated, user-defined structure. While I can simply run it by hand, that's obviously not great for reproducibility. I suppose an alternative to readLine would also work, if it could hand whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

[Make readline wait for input in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112370/make-readline-wait-for-input-in-r/27114322#27114322)
answered

when you use script mode, you should use readLines() for input and cat() for output, it's a strange design and I don't know why.

```
cat("a string please: ");
a <- readLines("stdin",n=1);
cat("You entered")
str(a);
cat( "\n" )
```