# Wait until user enter a value and based on that value run set of codes

Tags: r, loops, case

I want to make a program in which user will be asked to enter the location and based on that location value it should run a particular set of codes. It should wait until user enter the value of location.

```
readinteger <- function()
 { 
    n <- readline(prompt="Enter your location: ")
    n <- as.integer(n)
    if (is.na(n))
   return(as.integer(n))
  }

LC <- readinteger()
  if ( LC== 1)
{
 print(x)
}
 else if ( LC == 2)
 {
print(y)
} 
else 
print(z)
```

But here it proceeds to **if** loop directly and then ask to enter the location

Comment: Something like this? `readinteger <- function(){ n <- readline(prompt="Enter your location: "); n <- as.integer(n) ;if(is.na(n)) return(as.integer(n)); ifelse(n == 1, "code for 1", "code for 2") }
`

Comment: @Jimbou:  Your code works, but it requires semicolons because comment area has  stripped newlines. `readinteger <- function(){  n <- readline(prompt="Enter your location: ") ;  n <- as.integer(n) ;  if(is.na(n)){return(as.integer(n)) };    ifelse(n == 1, print("1 is n"), "code for 2") ;}` 
Note: This is essentially the same code as in @Jimbou 's comment

Comment: BTW , the problem with OP's code seems to be the line `if (is.na(n))`. It should be a negation `if( !is.na(n) )`

Comment: @R.S. not working..after putting semicolon it doesnt ask to Enter your Location..and run all codes direcctly...

Comment: @Jimbou not working..after putting semicolon it doesnt ask to Enter your Location..and run all codes direcctly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work fine if you include the `if` statements to control printing in your `readinteger` function. That way, `readline` will behave as expected (wait for input from the user) and then automatically move on to the printing commands.

```
readinteger <- function()
{ 
  n <- readline(prompt="Enter your location: ")
  n <- as.integer(n)

  x <- "You are at location one."
  y <- "You are at location two."
  z <- "You are lost."

  if ( n == 1)
    {
      print(x)
    }
  else if ( n == 2)
  {
    print(y)
  } 
  else 
    print(z)  
}

readinteger()
```

You had a `if (is.na(n))` in your code that wasn't doing anything, but my guess is you want to include a check to make sure the user has provided valid input. If so, you may find a `while` loop helpful, so the user can correct their input if there's an error. For example:

```
readinteger <- function()
{ 
  n <- NULL
  while( !is.integer(n) ){
    n <- readline(prompt="Enter your location: ")
    n <- try(suppressWarnings(as.integer(n)))
    if( is.na(n) ) {
      n <- NULL
      message("\nYou must enter an integer. Please try again.")
    }
  }

  x <- "You are at location one."
  y <- "You are at location two."
  z <- "You are lost."

  if ( n == 1)
    {
      print(x)
    }
  else if ( n == 2)
  {
    print(y)
  } 
  else 
    print(z)  
}

readinteger()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think it's got something to do with running the whole file at one go. 
It will work if you run it in Rsudio and run one step at a time, i.e., interactively.

According to the documentation of `?readline` : `In non-interactive use the result is as if the response was RETURN and the value is "". In which case, one solution is to  call the function again, as shown here : http://www.rexamples.com/4/Reading%20user%20input

I am not 100% sure it works without hitch.

For a more complex solution to your problem , you can see this question: [Make readline wait for input in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112370/make-readline-wait-for-input-in-r)

(Note: I'm adding this as answer simply for he sake of formatting. It's not really an answer )