# I have tried the following script in R using readline() to get input from the console but the program doesn't stop to take the input:

Tags: r, console.readline

I am trying to take 4 different inputs from the console in R, but the console takes the input only if I run the program line by line separately. If I send all the commands together there is no possibility to input the information:
I tried with the print commented and without. Thanks for your help.

```
grow <-readline(prompt='what do you grow - answer T or B or C?') 
#print(grow) 
size = readline(prompt='what size is your field?') 
#print(size) 
size = as.numeric(size) 
rain2 =readline(prompt='how much rain fell 2 months ago?') 
#print(rain2) 
rain2 = as.numeric(rain2) 
rain1 =readline(prompt='how much rain fell last month?') 
#print(rain1) 
rain1 = as.numeric(rain1)
```

Comment: How are you running the script? `readline()` only works in interactive mode. You can test this with `interactive()`.

Comment: Take a look at [Make readline wait for input in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27112370/4752675)

Comment: thanks I will try these out