# Input variable names in R via readline

Tags: r

I'm quite sure that somebody already asked this question, but I don't really find it.

I need to make some analysis and just want to make a script, in which I want to input the names of the table or the variable via readline, so that I can adjust the function depending on the input.

```
my.table <- readline(prompt="Enter name of table: ")
my.variable1<- readline(prompt="Enter name of variable 1: ")
my.variable2<- readline(prompt="Enter name of variable 2: ")
surv_object <- Surv(time = my.table$my.variable1, event = my.table$my.variable2)
```

This actutally does not work out. Even `view(my.table)` simply returns NULL.

Where should I look up this problem? What have I done wrong?

Thank you for your help!

Thomas

Comment: `my.variable1` and `my.variable2` are not in `my.table` (which is a string, not a list or data frame) as you assigned all of them to the global environment, so `my.table$my.variable1` and `my.table$my.variable2` should error out with `Error in my.table$my.variable1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: I just want to refer to variables in another table und just store them for the procedure. For e.g. 1) Enter name of table: data 2) enter name of variable: variable1 3) enter name of variable2: variable2. this should create the function surv_object <- Surv(time = data$variable1, event = data$variable2)

Answer (score 1):

The use of eval(parse(text= ...)) is viewed with suspicion by most experienced R programmers. If the goal is to access an existing R object that has some column names, then this would be a preferred approach:

Let's assume that your user knows that `mtcars` is in the workspace, and that it's variable names are:

You also need a function  to wait for input; otherwise the `readline` just gets an empty character value and moves on to the next line of code. See an earlier answer on this point: [Make readline wait for input in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112370/make-readline-wait-for-input-in-r)

```
 #Warning: this does not seem to work in RStudio because they assign stdin to /dev/null
my.table <- cat("Enter name of table: "); readLines("stdin", n=1); cat( "\n")
my.variable <- cat("Enter name of variable 1: "); readLines("stdin",n=1); cat( "\n")
my.variable2<- cat("Enter name of variable 2: "); readLines("stdin",n=1);cat( "\n")

my.obj <- get(my.table)

surv_object <- Surv(time = my.obj[my.variable1], event = my.obj[my.variable2])
```

If I had not used the object name (input as a character value) to access and assign to a name that was predetermined it would have been a big PITA to always use the character "name", since R names (AKA `symbol`'s) are not actually quoted since they are not of type character but rather of type "language".

In RStudio I somehow need to create a function to do the input. But I haven't gotten a tested version to succeed. Maybe it needs to have a shiny interface?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your main issue is how to convert text to an expression. Is this what you are looking for? This is probably skirting best practice in more way than one. The user would need to know the table object names and variable names. Errors will not be obvious. The code will simply do as it is told.

Also if you are using RStudio, check out `?rstudioapi::showPrompt`.

Start with a couple of tables:

```
table1 <- mtcars
table2 <- iris
```

Run through the prompts. I am entering in "table1", "wt", "hp".

```
my.table <- readline(prompt="Enter name of table: ")
my.variable1<- readline(prompt="Enter name of variable 1: ")
my.variable2<- readline(prompt="Enter name of variable 2: ")
```

Using `eval(parse(.))`, convert the `my.table` string into the `data.frame()` object.

```
new.table <- eval(parse(text = my.table))
```

Reference the two columns.

```
new.table[, c(my.variable1, my.variable2)]
```

Comment: You should probably make clear that this requires knowing both an existing object name and the column names and errors will result if any are input incorrectly.

Comment: Added some words to that extent. I agree with you. But I viewed the crux of the problem as evaluating strings as expressions, so here it is.