# R language user input if condition

Tags: r

I am getting input from user for num variable in R-lang and checking whether the number is greater than some value using if condition, but its keep giving this below error

```
num = as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter a number: "))
flag = 0
# prime numbers are greater than 1
if(num > 1) {
# check for factors
    flag = 1
 }
```

Enter a number:

> Error in if (num > 1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Execution halted

pls help
thanks

here is my code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: my code is above

Comment: Please go through the links I gave you and edit accordingly.

Comment: your code works correctly but don't run all lines together. Run the first line, enter the number and then run the remaining lines. You need to take the input from the user.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the entire block of code at once, you get this error :

```
> num = as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter a number: "))
Enter a number: flag = 0
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> # prime numbers are greater than 1
> if(num > 1) {
+   # check for factors
+   flag = 1
+ }
Error in if (num > 1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>
```

You need to enter the number first and then run subsequent lines

```
> num = as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter a number: "))
Enter a number: 5
```

Once the number is entered, you can proceed further.

```
> flag = 0
> # prime numbers are greater than 1
> if(num > 1) {
+     # check for factors
+     flag = 1
+ }
> print(flag)
[1] 1
>
```

Read this thread for further clarification :
[Make readline wait for input in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112370/make-readline-wait-for-input-in-r)