# How to stop taking input from standard input in rstudio

Tags: r, input, rstudio, stdin

I actually want to take input from R in script mode (i.e. I'll copy and run the program written in an RScript) and I am using the readLines function for that (since I've come to know that readline function is meant to be used only in interactive mode). When I run the following code (in rstudio),

```
k = as.integer(readLines("stdin",n=1))
x = c()
```

it starts taking input, but the problem is that it doesn't stop taking input. Even if I click on the red octagon, it is not stopping and neither am I able to quit the session. I've to restart the computer. Any help on how can we stop it?? (I'll also be very happy if you suggest some better function to take and process input in script mode)

Comment: Does the top answer from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112370/make-readline-wait-for-input-in-r work for you? Key is that you need to call `readLines` in non-interactive mode (e.g., using Rscript)

Comment: @Vandenman, no, it doesn't work. It is still hanging. I am already asking for the case of calling `readLines` in non-interactive mode(script mode).

Comment: just to make sure, you're calling the script from command line with something like `Rscript test.R`? And what do you get if you put `print(interactive())` right before the call to `readLines`?

Comment: @Vandenman, I am not using command line. I am using RStudio. I select everything in the RScript (using `Ctrl+A`) and then press `Ctrl+Enter` to run it.

Comment: then you're in interactive mode, so you should just use `readline`

Comment: @Vandenman, I am not in interactive mode and therefore `readline` function does not work. You should read the question in the link you suggested in your first comment.

Comment: Rather than selecting all text, try `Ctrl+Shift+A` or `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` in combination with `readline`. That will call `source` on the file you're using and will wait for user input before continuing. If you prefer I can post an example. From `?interactive`, you can read that GUI consoles, like Rstudio, always use R in interactive mode.

Comment: @Vandenman, I am compelled to do it in that way. I've to give a lot of input lines at once, but that seems not to be possible like this.